# Print input box run time value by window.print() method

Tags: javascript, html

I have a table with multiple rows (records) that I am creating using a loop. In each row I have a text box in which I will insert any value. I want to print this table data through window.print() method or any other suitable method, with the text box value that I have inserted using javascript.

I have tried so much but nothing worked well.

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Main Page</title>
</head>
<body>
<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="5" id="tabledata" border="1">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th>Id</th>
      <th>Date</th>
      <th>Profile Id</th>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Price</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>109</td>
      <td>01-10-2013</td>
      <td>15500</td>
      <td>Test Name</td>
      <td><input type="text" style="width: 52px;"></td>

    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>96</td>
      <td>01-10-2013</td>
      <td>78394</td>
      <td>Ram</td>
      <td><input type="text" style="width: 52px;"></td>

    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>71</td>
      <td>01-10-2013</td>
      <td>85868</td>
      <td>Poppy Daisy</td>
      <td><input type="text" style="width: 52px;"></td>

    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>68</td>
      <td>01-10-2013</td>
      <td>14463</td>
      <td>Amy Freddie</td>
      <td><input type="text" style="width: 52px;"></td>

    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>109</td>
      <td>01-10-2013</td>
      <td>44172</td>
      <td>Mohan</td>
      <td><input type="text" style="width: 52px;"></td>

    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

This is my table structure in an example format but this is not fixed because I am fetching data from my database. I want to print whole data shown in table .

Comment: There are 5 columns in the table, 4 with labels(printed data) and 1 with empty text box in which user can fill any value. And I want to print whole table data including text box values.

Comment: please elaborate the problem. Dont add comments but edit your question first. It hardly makes the problem clear...

Comment: If possible add some code.

Answer (score 0):

Create a method for printing, which replaces your text boxes with the values in them, and then call `window.print()`

Assuming you use jQuery:

```
function print_flat() {
    // hide fields, show values
    $("input[type=text]").each(function() {
        $("<div>" + $(this).val() + "</div>").insertBefore($(this));
        $(this).hide();
    });

    window.print(); // print (modal)

    // remove values, show fields
    $("input[type=text]").each(function() {
        $(this).prev("div").remove();
        $(this).show(); 
    });
}
```

The above function goes through all the text fields, and adds their contents in a div placed before the text field, then hides the text fields and prints the page.

**Update:** since the print dialog is modal, it runs the code following it after the print dialog is closed, so we can restore the state of the page then. Try it here: http://jsfiddle.net/aorcsik/hZkZa/

Comment: @aorcsik... Thanks a lot. It helped me a lot but it also hides all the text boxes on my webpage.

Comment: @aorcsik... Is there anything by which we can print the document with text boxes values and do not hide our web page text boxes.

Comment: @localhost added some changes that restore the state of the page

Answer (score 0):

just add this style your text box will be hide in print

```
<style media="print">
    input{display:none;}
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

What I get from your problem description, I think you want the following solution-

```
<body>
    <table border=1>
        <script>
            try
            {
                for(i=1;i<=10;i++)
                {
                    j=0;
                    document.write("<tr><td><input type=text id=t"+i+" onblur=\"for(j=0;j<getElementsByName('td"+i+"').length;j++)document.getElementsByName('td"+i+"')[j].innerHTML=this.value\">\
                <td name=td"+i+">\
                <td name=td"+i+">\
                <td name=td"+i+">\
                <td name=td"+i+">");
                }
            }
            catch(err)
            {
                alert(err);
            }
        </script>
    </table>
</body>
```

Now **in the textbox type in something** and when the textbox **loses focus** the **text in of the textbox get inside the columns of the table**.

Check this in the **[fiddle_solution_page](http://jsfiddle.net/rajesh38/87Vvh/)**